# On orientation change touch events recognized for half the screen(portrait width)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController which handles the gestures so I have not done anything with it. I disabled auto-layout in my storyboard so that I could use autoresize to fill the screen with views.

I have a tabbar and if I reload the page with the tabbaritem. The gesture are working.

How can I make the touch/gesture handler resize on orientation change?

Comment: Why are you trying to resize the touch/gesture handler area? They're attached to a control or UIView. When the view/control is resized, so is the touch/gesture handler area.

Comment: Like I said in the question I use default gesture settings of the pageviewcontroller does that mean the pageviewcontroller doesn't resize? (I can't auto-resize it in the inspector)

Comment: Gestures for PageViewController will be the frame of the pageViewController. For your case, I'd have the autorotationmask set for the horizontal/vertical for automatic orientation change handling. How are you using the PageViewController? You said autoresize to fill the screen with views - PageViewController is mainly used for tutorial images when the app is first installed for new users. It sounds like you're using the wrong VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kevindew.me/post/18579273258/where-to-progmatically-lay-out-views-in-ios-5-and

In the above link you will find usefull information about laying out and handling orientation changes. Also I had this problem once on a device with lower iOS version if your version can be updated you can try that however it's not a fix. I recommend to check the link and see if your views are properly layed out.